# Saving and using Custom Field in user settings/profile “Checkbox list”

Tags: custom-field, tags

Referencing this question:

[How to add/save Custom Field in user settings/profile "Checkbox list"](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6690/how-to-add-save-custom-field-in-user-settings-profile-checkbox-list/198525?noredirect=1#comment289108_198525)

I've been trying to get this working, but am having a few issues. I'm using the following line to query the database:

```
$tags = get_the_author_meta( 'user_interests', $user_ID );
<?php $query = new WP_Query( array( 'tag__in' => array( $tags) ) ); ?>
```

and the query returns blank. If I print_r the $tags I get

Array ( [74] => 74 )

and if I replace the $tags with 74 directly I get the current content returned. I'm missing something simple, aren't I? Could anyone point me in the right direction?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got it - just use this:

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query( array( 'tag__in' => $tags ) ); ?>
```

Comment: Just to clarify for others - `$tags` was already an array in the correct format for the `tags__in` parameter. Wrapping it in another array "nested" it too deep and `WP_Query` was unable to understand the argument.